# JBDC / H2 Почему занимает и не освобождает память?

Tags: java, база-данных

Снизу приведу свой тестовый код. База данных H2. В примере при запуске первые 15 секунд потребление ОЗУ составляет 11 мб. Далее идет создание таблицы и многократное обращение к БД для записи данных. В этот момент возрастает потребление оперативной памяти. После завершения цикла с обращениями, подключения к базе уже нет, но ОЗУ всё так же занята. Почему так? Разве память не должна освободиться? И как этого добиться? И вообще, что это за занятый объём? Если увеличить количество повторений цикла, занятой памяти больше не станет, или станет незначительно больше. Заранее спасибо) Постигаю работу с СУБД))

[image: Программа запущенна, ждём таймер. Потребление - минимум памяти]

[image: Цикл записи завершен. Работает таймер. Обращения к базе нет, но память занята]

```
package h2test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class H2CreateExample {
    
    private static String jdbcURL = "jdbc:h2:~/biba";
    private static String jdbcUsername = "sa";
    private static String jdbcPassword = "";

    private static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private static void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
        for(Throwable e: ex) {
            if(e instanceof SQLException) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
                System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
                System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
                Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                while (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static final String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE `data` (\n"
            + " `id` BIGINT auto_increment,\n"
            + " `date` DATE NOT NULL,\n"
            + " `dataText` TEXT,\n"
            + " `dataImage` JAVA_OBJECT,\n"
            + " PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
            + ");";
    
    private static void createDataTable() throws SQLException {
        //Устанавливаем подключение к БД и создаём оператор подключения
        try (Connection connection = getConnection(); Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute(createTableSQL); //Выполняем запрос
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
    }
    
    private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO `data`" +
            " (`date`, `dataText`, `dataImage`) VALUES " +
            " (?, ?, ?);"; //ПОПРАВИТЬ ЗАПРОС
    
    public static long add(Date date,
            String dataText,
            ImageIcon image) throws SQLException {
        
        long result = -1;
        
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
                //Передаём оператору SQL запрос, а так же запрос на возврат ключа
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL)) {
            preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, dataText);
            preparedStatement.setObject(3, image);
            
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        
        createDataTable();
        System.out.println("Таблица создана");
        
        File file = new File("/home/drevnicky/Изображения/black.jpg");
        ImageIcon image = null;
        
        try {
            image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file));
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        
        for(int k = 0; k<50; k++) {
            add(new Date(), "Какой-то текст", image);
            System.out.println("Цикл " + k);
        }
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Чёт нигде не вижу close или try с ресурсами

Comment: В методе add() - try (Connection connection = getConnection(); При окончании try соединение закрывается автоматически, судя по гайду. Если все же впихнуть close() ситуация не меняется(

Comment: А вижу, ну тогда хз